# how can I make sure object doesn't leave form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I have an object in my form and it can move with the arrow keys. If my object tries to leave the form then the interaction should blocked or comeback at where it tried to leave or will teleport to the center of the form. How can I do this? My object is a picturebox.
This is the only thing I have now:

```
If picturebox1.location.x < 0 or picturebox1.location.y < 0 then
picturebox1.location = new point(10,10)
End if
```

Is there a code to say if it leaves the form?

Comment: Attach them solidly. Don't allow them to run. Seriously though, you're on the right track; you need to check all 4 directions though.

Comment: Sorry I tought vb.net and vba were the same. I'm using vb.net. Can you tell me how I can do this?

Comment: I prefer staples, but glue will also work.

Comment: Look at the `picturebox1` members available to you. Wouldn't `Size` and `Location` seem of importance in solving this?

Comment: Not really helping

Comment: I tried to use the size of the form and put it in a code just like I did with y < 0, x<0 but it didn't work because it is not exact.

Comment: Think about it: position refers to the top-left corner of a thing, so if you want to check if that thing is partially rendered outside the form, you need to check that its X position minus its Width is less than the width of the form's client area to check the right edge; check the Y position minus its Height being less than the height of the form's client area to check the bottom edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function can do it for you. As stated in comments, you needed to also check the container boundaries.

```
Private Sub moveControlInContainer(control As Control, container As Control, x As Integer, y As Integer)
    Dim newLocation = New System.Drawing.Point(control.Location.X + x, control.Location.Y + y)
    If newLocation.X < 0 Then
        newLocation.X = 0
    ElseIf newLocation.X + control.Width > container.ClientRectangle.Width Then
        newLocation.X = container.ClientRectangle.Width - control.Width
    End If
    If newLocation.Y < 0 Then
        newLocation.Y = 0
    ElseIf newLocation.Y + control.Height > container.ClientRectangle.Height Then
        newLocation.Y = container.ClientRectangle.Height - control.Height
    End If
    control.Location = newLocation
End Sub
```

Call it like this

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    Dim v = 5
    Dim x = 0, y = 0
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Left
            x = -1
        Case Keys.Right
            x = 1
        Case Keys.Up
            y = -1
        Case Keys.Down
            y = 1
    End Select
    moveControlInContainer(Me.PictureBox1, Me, x * v, y * v)
End Sub
```

Substitute `Me` for whatever container the PictureBox is in (if in a panel or group box etc.), or if it's just on the form, leave as is. You can also call the function from the `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` event handlers but use the appropriate event args. Use `v` to control the number of pixels to move per key press.

**Edit** to address questions in comment:

About [Control.ClientRectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The client area of a control is the bounds of the control, minus the nonclient elements such as scroll bars, borders, title bars, and menus.
>
> Because client coordinates are relative to the upper-left corner of the client area of the control, the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the rectangle returned by this property are (0,0). You can use this property to obtain the size and coordinates of the client area of the control for tasks such as drawing on the surface of the control.

`moveControlInContainer` has four arguments:

- `control As Control`, The control you wish to move.
- `container As Control`, The container which has the control in it. If there is no container other than the Form, just pass the Form.
- `x As Integer`, The number of pixels to move to the right. If moving to the left, use a negative number.
- `y As Integer` The number of pixels to move down. If moving up, use a negative number.

The location of the picture is the coordinates of the upper-left pixel of the picture. When you are moving it, if you only check that the location is positive, then you will be able to move the picture anywhere other than past the left or upper borders of the Form. You must also check the right and bottom borders. But since you are using the upper left pixel location only, you must also include the height and width of the picture. This is how we do that in the `moveControlInContainer` function

- First, calculate the new location from x and y.
- If the horizontal coordinate is less than zero, set it to zero. This prevents the control from moving past the left border of the form.
- If the horizontal coordinate was not less than zero, check if the horizontal coordinate plus the width of the picture goes outside the boundary of the form (client rectangle). If the control's horizontal position plus the width is greater than the container's width, set it to the extreme point while keeping it in the container (container width minus control width).
- Do similar with the vertical coordinate

Comment: Thank you for helping, the code perfect. But can you explain me the code because I don't know what, movecontrolincontainer is or clientrectangle. Sorry I am an amateur in programming.